# NameError: name 'error' is not defined

Tags: python-3.6, scapy, nameerror

So I was making a cheat program for a game using scapy, and when I ran it in visual studios it worked fine, but when I say in cmd

```
python myprogram.py
```

It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ScapyTest.py", line 135, in <module>
  sniff(prn=action)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 
592, in sniff
  sel = select([s],[],[],remain)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\supersocket.py", 
line 38, in fileno
  return self.ins.fileno()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", 
line 232, in fileno
  error("Cannot get selectable PCAP fd on Windows")
NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

Im unsure if it literally means it doesnt know what an error is, or if there is some logical reason behind it not knowing what an error is. It is something with sniff but im not sure what. There are also no errors in my code so I dont know why its saying this

Comment: What version of scapy are you using?  Did you try upgrading to the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an old bug. You should get the current development version (from the [official repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), install it and try again.